# How to use .values() with enumerated type Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, enums

I am trying to use the values method to find the given value of an enumerated type. For some reason it says that I have to create a values() method, but that should be a built in method (at least I think so). Here is the code that I am having problems with:

---

```
public class Suit {
public enum SUIT{
    CLUBS("Clubs"), HEARTS("Hearts"), SPADES("Spades"), DIAMONDS("Diamonds");

    private String suitType;

    SUIT(String suitType){
        this.suitType = suitType;
    }
    public String getSuit(){
        return suitType;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
public class Rank {
private static int ACEVal;

public void setACEVal(int ACEVal){
    this.ACEVal = ACEVal;
}
public int getACEVal(){
    return ACEVal;
}

public enum RANK{
    ACE(14, "Ace"),
    TWO(2, "Two"),
    THREE(3, "Three"),
    FOUR(4, "Four"),
    FIVE(5, "Five"),
    SIX(6, "Six"),
    SEVEN(7, "Seven"),
    EIGHT(8, "Eight"),
    NINE(9, "Nine"),
    TEN(10, "Ten"),
    JACK(10, "Jack"),
    QUEEN(10, "Queen"),
    KING(10, "King");

    public int rankVal;
    String cardType;

    RANK(int rankValue, String cardType){
        rankVal = rankValue;
        this.cardType = cardType;
    }

    public int getRankVal(){
        return rankVal;
    }

    public String getCardType(){
        return cardType;
    }
}
}
```

---

```
public class CreateDeck {
ArrayList<CreateCard> DeckArray = new ArrayList<CreateCard>(); //uses the cards that were created in CreateCard to load into the ArrayList

public void createDeck(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){ //loops thirteen times for each different type of card (Ace, Two, Three, etc...){
        Rank rankNum = Rank.values()[i]; //gets the type of rank
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){ //loops for the four different suits (Clubs, Spades, Hearts, Diamonds)
            CreateCard card = new CreateCard(rankNum, Suit.values()[j]);
            DeckArray.add(card); //adds the created card to the deck
        }
}
```

---

Why am I unable to use .values()?

Comment: You'll want to post your code for "Suit" as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code for the Rank class.

Comment: Well, is Rank an enum ?

Comment: Considier to change your for-loops with index to `for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) ...` which is much easier.

Comment: I have edited the code, sorry about that.

Comment: Your enums are Suit.SUITS and RANK. Yet you are calling Suit.values and Rank.values. Notice that SUITS is embedded in Suit. RANK is not embedded in Rank. Anyway values() doesn't exist because you are calling it on the wrong type. Watch your names carefully.

Comment: RANK seems to be also embedded in Rank

Comment: @StefaanNeyts yes you are correct. I missed that due to the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler adds the values() method. It is static and returning an array of the enum constants.

public static E[] values();

You can iterate over the values instead of using an index. Watch your names, the enums you provided are in uppercase!

```
for(RANK rank : RANK.values()) { ... }
for(SUIT suit : SUIT.values()) { ... }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Enum is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types. More information about enums, including descriptions of the implicitly declared methods synthesized by the compiler, can be found in section 8.9 of The Java™ Language Specification.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

The keyword enum is just a short way to say extends Enum<>. That's the reason why you can't extend enums from another class: single inheritance in Java.

Comment: Edited with more info for the down voting people.

Comment: I think people downvoted because you said values does not return an array. It does.

Comment: Indeed.. Apologies. Editing my own post to correct.